# Jade doesn't keep formatting for rendered html

Tags: pug

I'm using the command line for index.jade with
    jade --watch .
The rendered index.html has all white-space removed. Is there a way to tell jade not to remove the white-space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jade-lang.com/api/

```
options: {
   pretty: true;
}
```

Comment: What do I do with this?

Comment: Place in your gruntfile.js or gulpfile.js jade options section. I never use jade from command line, but as in API you need to use jade --pretty --watch

Comment: Thanks, man! That's the one I needed. I have no idea how to use gulp or grunt files. So I do everything from the console.

Comment: I can't imagine how to work without complex task runner, it's save lots of time. If you want you can try my grunt config for jade+stylus+js: https://github.com/KonZee/MarkupBoilerplate

Comment: I'm not that advanced. Let me learn the basic technologies like jade, SASS, etc. then I can learn some grunt automation. As of now, it's all Greek to me :)

Comment: I started to work with ready grunt config, learn it step by step and alter for myself. At start it was magic black box : )